# JAX-Qname is not found in Maven Repository

Tags: maven

I am using one of the jax-qname.jar(1.1) in my project and but the maven build fails as the jar is not found. Can anyone tell me if this jar part of maven central repository.

Comment: share us your dependency

Answer (score 0):

Yeah its available in maven central repository, verify whether you added following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
  <artifactId>jax-qname</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

As this available in maven central repository since it is showing up in mvn central repo search. Refer to below link:

http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|jax-qname

Answer (score 0):

`jax-qname.jar` is a part of the Java Web Service Developer Pack and so some kind of default artifacts so it is certainly availble in **The Central Repository**. `maven` by default has access to this central repo and no additional configuration is required within you *settings.xml* file. So, as @pramod.nikam.dev suggested, you need to make sure you have the right depedency declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency entry

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
  <artifactId>jax-qname</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

does exist in the common Maven repo, but it only contains the pom, not the jar. Due to weird licensing, the jar must be downloaded from Sun (or, now, the Sun-that-was). The pom gives a download URL for the jar, but this URL no longer exists, instead redirecting you into Oracle's unhelpful innards. Likewise, the JAX-RPC project does provide downloads. You might be able to find in in the [Gradle Artifactory](http://gradle.artifactoryonline.com/gradle/libs/javax/xml/jax-qname/1.1/).